# yowsup to Whatsapp Messaging

Tags: whatsapp, yowsup

I had setup Yowsup on my server. I followed [this guide](https://www.unixmen.com/send-nagios-alert-notification-using-whatsapp/) and setup everything without any error. But at the last step, i.e. sending a message, it doesn't throw any error but the message doesn't reach Whatsapp on my mobile.

### Below is the output for your reference.

```
irrt-perf:/usr/local/nagios/yowsup_new/yowsup-master$ ./yowsup-cli demos -c yowsup-cli_Srini.config -s 919886655650 "Hai"

yowsup-cli  v2.0.15
yowsup      v2.5.0
Copyright (c) 2012-2016 Tarek Galal


This software is provided free of charge. Copying and redistribution is encouraged.

If you appreciate this software and you would like to support future
development please consider donating.

irrt-perf:/usr/local/nagios/yowsup_new/yowsup-master$
```

there is no getting any (success/failure) message after send !

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that most people has changed their env.py during registration to:

```
DEFAULT = "Android"
```

So you need to add "-E s40" to your command:

```
./yowsup-cli demos -c yowsup-cli_Srini.config -s 919886655650 "Hai" -E s40
```

If this doesn't work then go back to your ENV folder and change insde the file "env_android.py" for the following code

```
_MD5_CLASSES = "J5txjufBsNxR0JTudlKRzg=="
_VERSION = "2.17.281"
```

I hope that helps.